# Redactor imageUpload and Laravel 4 Resource Controllers

Tags: laravel, wysiwyg, image-uploading, redactor

I've seen several solutions for the Redactor imageUpload using a dedicated route, however I choose to use a resource controller to do all the routing.

The markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        {{ Form::model($page, array('method' => 'put', 'route' => array('pages.update', $page->id), 'files' => true)) }}

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                {{ Form::label('title', 'Title') }}
                {{ Form::text('title') }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                {{ Form::label('body', 'Content') }}
                {{ Form::textarea('body') }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
            {{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'button')) }}
            <a href="{{ URL::route('pages.index') }}" class="btn btn-large">Cancel</a>
        </div>

    {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $(this).foundation();

  $('#body').redactor({

  iframe: true,
  css: "{{ url('sleddog-assets/stylesheets/app.css') }}",
  imageUpload: 'pages.edit'
  });

});
</script>
```

The code:

```
class PagesController extends \BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //$pages = Page::all();
    //return $pages;
    return \View::make('admin.pages.pages')->with('pages', Page::all());
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return \View::make('admin.pages.create');
    //return "Create";
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $validation = new PageValidator;

    if ($validation->passes()) {
        // $file = Input::file('file');
        // if(Input::upload('file', 'public/images', $file['name'])) {
        //  $image = Response::json(array('filelink' => 'images/' . $file['name']));
        // }

        $page = new Page;
        $page->title = Input::get('title');
        $page->slug = Str::get('slug');
        $page->body = Input::get('body');
        $page->user_id = Sentry::getUser()->id;


        $page->save();

        return Redirect::route('admin.pages.edit');
    }

    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation->errors);
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    return \View::make('admin.pages.show')->with('page', Page::find($id));
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    return \View::make('admin.pages.edit')->with('page', Page::find($id));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    $validation = new PageValidator;

    if ($validation->passes())
    {
        // $file = Input::file('file');
        // if(Input::upload('file', 'public/images', $file['name'])) {
        //  $image = Response::json(array('filelink' => 'images/' . $file['name']));
        // }
        $page = Page::find($id);
        $page->title   = Input::get('title');
        $page->slug    = Str::slug(Input::get('title'));
        $page->body    = Input::get('body');
        $page->user_id = Sentry::getUser();



        $page->save();

        return Redirect::route('pages.edit', $page->id);
    }

    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation->errors);
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $page = Page::find($id);
    return Redirect::route('admin.pages.pages');
}

}
```

My questions:

In the markup, where do I aim the imageUpload? pages.edit?
In the controller, where do put the code that is required to get Redactor's imageUpload to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using redactor's imageupload feature, you have to write a custom method for it. I've attached an example

```
public function postUpload(){

    $file = Input::file('file');

    $destinationPath = 'uploads/';
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename  = uniqid($file->getFilename()) . '.' . $extension;
    $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);

    if( $upload_success ) {
        return Response::json($data = array(
            'filelink' => Request::root() . '/' .$destinationPath . $filename
        ), 200);
    } else {
        return Response::json('error', 400);
    }
}
```

Redactor will become something like this:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
imageUpload: base + '/url/to/controller'
});
```

For more information you can read this
http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files

Comment: Your solution has helped quite a bit.  The only problem I am having now, is that I am getting a broken image result... If I right click, get image URL, it's correct.  It is also properly saving the image.  The only thing I can think that is causing this problem is that I get this funky url {"filelink":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/public\/uploads\/phpgldSn851f8cff91ff61.jpg"} in the sources of my web developer tool... Any idea why that is? Thanks

Comment: I'd vote you up if I could by the way... I was also thinking, do I perhaps need to declare a route for the uploads directory? Is that why it's not showing? Thanks

Comment: Getting such an error for each image: GET http://localhost:8000/public/uploads/phpYagTHb51f8cec69fa85.jpg 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Got it.  The controller doesn't require an absolute path!  Once again thanks for all the help!  return Response::json($data = array(
            'filelink' => '/uploads/' . $filename
        ), 200);

Comment: In my case it did, but if it worked out for you that is fine :) (Sorry for the late reply tho)

Comment: Would be awesome if you could accept the answer. Glad that it worked out